# toggle caching / cookies

Tags: jquery, cookies, toggle

I’m using the jQuery toggle function for my navigation. 
By default the Authors toggle is visible, the Archives toggle is closed.

http://jsfiddle.net/TeDFs/4/

My problem is that when the users switches to another page the toggles reset themselves.

For example, when the user closes the Authors toggle and opens the Archive toggle and then navigates to another page the default settings are loaded.

I read that it’s possible to store the settings via cookies but I’m absolutely new to jQuery and it would be great if somebody could help me out!

HTML

```
<div id="authors" class="widget">
<h2 class="widget-title-visible">Authors</h2>
<div class="toggle">
    <div class="submenu">
        <ul>
            <li>Name 1</li>
            <li>Name 2</li>
            <li>Name 3</li>
            <li>Name 3</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
<div id="archives" class="widget">
<h2 class="widget-title">Archiv</h2>
<div class="toggle hidden">
    <div class="submenu">       
        <ul>
            <li>November 2012</li>
            <li>Oktober 2012</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>​
```

jQuery

```
function toggleWidgets() {
    jQuery('.widget-title').addClass('plus'); 

    jQuery('.widget-title-visible').addClass('minus'); 

    jQuery('.widget-title').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('plus').toggleClass('minus').next().toggle(180);
    });

    jQuery('.widget-title-visible').click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass('minus').toggleClass('plus').next().toggle(180);
    });
} 

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    toggleWidgets();
} )​
```

CSS

```
.hidden{
    display:none;
}

.plus {
    background: url(http://moargh.de/daten/sidebar_arrows.png) 0 5px no-repeat;
    padding: 0 0 0 12px;
}
.minus {
    background: url(http://moargh.de/daten/sidebar_arrows.png) 0 -10px no-repeat;
    padding: 0 0 0 12px;
}
```

​

Comment: Marking my detailed reply as "answer" you really help. Please click the "check mark" below my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    var expires;
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    else expires = "";
    document.cookie = name + "=" + value + expires + "; path=/";
}


function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEq = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ')
            c = c.substring(1, c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEq) == 0)
            return c.substring(nameEq.length, c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

function eraseCookie(name) {
    createCookie(name, "", -1);
}
```

Here are functions to read/write cookies. You can keep you settings as you wish :)

If you want to toggle the visibility of both divs, just use the "id" of the div as the cookie name and save in the cookie "true" or "false" as it's visible or not.

When you click the div, get it's "id" and visibility and

```
var divId = $(this).attr("id");
var visible = false;
if($(this).isVisible())
    visible = true;

createCookie(divId, visible, 1);
```

And when you reload the page just

```
var visibleAuthors = readCookie("authors");
var visibleArchives = readCookie("archives")
```

Parse the result of the cookie when loading the page and then show the div you want too

Comment: Thank you very much for the code but I don’t understand how to implement it so it fits to my needs. Is it possible that you tell me how it’s cutomized?

Comment: Is the answer ok? Have you implemented it successfully ?

Comment: I’m afraid I didn’t get it to work yet … It would help me if you update my fiddle so I understand where to put the code and which parts can/must be customized. http://jsfiddle.net/TeDFs/4/

Comment: I've added the code in the http://jsfiddle.net/TeDFs/37/. It doesn't work there because I don't think they allow you to craete cookie on their domain, but try in your code and tell me if it works. It's not the final code, but it should give you the general idea.

Comment: I'm gonna go to be now, given the fact that it's 2:15 AM. Hope my code helped. Please remember to mark as answered :)